# ¿Por qué MDBCarouselItem en REACT no se renderiza con id en 0?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy haciendo un carousel en React con ayuda de los componentes MDBCarousel y MDBCarouselItem de mdb-react-ui-kit. La forma en que lo hago es dinámicamente:

```
<div id={style.banner}>
    {catalogos.map(catalogo => (
        <MDBCarousel key={catalogo.id} showControls showIndicators fade>
            {catalogo.banner.map((b, id) => (
                <MDBCarouselItem
                    key={id+1}
                    className="w-100 d-block"
                    itemId={id+1}
                    src={b}
                    height="300vh"
                />
            ))}
        </MDBCarousel>
    ))}
</div>
```

Dependiendo de la cantidad de imagenes que hay en la Base de Datos, es la cantidad de items que se ingresarán en el carousel, el detalle es cuando todos los items se ingresarón, en el navegador se muestran todos excepto el primer item con **id=0**, todos los demás se visualizan, pero cuando **aumento un 1 a cada id** (como en el código anterior), ya se pueden visualizar todos los items.

¿Alguién sabe por qué esta pasando esto?

Comment: Prueba con `itemId={id}`

Comment: Ya lo intenté y no funciona, de hecho acabo de ver que funciona bien con ````key={id}```` sin aumento en el id, pero específicamente en **itemId** no funciona

Comment: Verifica en la documentacion de `MDBCarouselItem` si puede recibir id's con valor 0.

Comment: He estado leyendo la documentación y en el [enlace](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/components/carousel/) lo único que menciona es lo siguiente **_The .active class needs to be added to one of the slides otherwise the carousel will not be visible. Also be sure to set a unique id on the MDBCarouselItem._** Pero no menciona o explica nada más sobre la composición de los identificadores o que deben de iniciar a partir de 1.